# In Eclipse, is there a possibility to have a setting in code that depends on export vs run/debug action?

Tags: android, eclipse

I like to call certain different methods and set certain variables in my app based on whether it is just being run/debugged in Eclipse versus creating an Export app.

Is there a way that I can check in code whether tha app started from within Eclipse vs from an exported app file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

Use the BuildConfig.DEBUG boolean that is automatically set to false when exporting and otherwise set to true.

Cheers!